# Can you recover a file after removing the file using git?

Tags: git

Suppose I am in branch 1, commit `file1`, and then checkout branch 2 from branch 1. On branch 2, I use `git rm file1`. If I go back to branch 1 (`git checkout branch 1`), will I get `file1` back?

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: Toby I did not want to try it and lose my file, but I should have maybe done an experiment :)

Comment: create another git repo, create a file, create 2 branches and try it out.

Comment: Also I saw a post recommending the use of git rm --cached, so I did not understand if I needed to use this.

Comment: That just removes it from the staging area (index).  That's mostly useful if you've used `git add` but not `git commit`.

Answer (score 1):

> will I get file1 back?

Yes, of course. It's part of branch 1, and you haven't merged branch 2 into branch 1, so the file still exists in branch 1.

Comment: Then why do people recommend using git rm --cached?

Comment: @vkaul11: But surely they don't recommend it in a context that applies here?